# Existence of countable transitive models.

Tags: set-theory

I have read that $\mathrm{ZF}$ has a transitive model iff it has a **countable** transitive model. I am interested in generalizations of this result. In particular:

> **Question.** Let $\varphi$ and $\Psi$ denote a sentence and a set of sentences (respectively) in the first-order language of set theory. If $\mathrm{ZF}+\Psi +\varphi$ proves that there exists a transitive model of $\mathrm{ZF}+\varphi$, does $\mathrm{ZF}+\Psi+\varphi$ necessarily prove that there exist a **countable** transitive model $\mathrm{ZF}+\varphi$?

**Addendum.** I'm especially interested in the case where the axiom of choice (or a weaker fragment thereof) is an element of $\Psi.$ That being said, the comments suggest that the answer to the full question is "no," so I'd be interested to hear of a counterexample to the full claim.

Comment: Yes. The same Löwenheim-Skolem + Mostowski collapse argument also works for extensions of ZF.

Comment: @Miha: Not quite. If $\sf DC$ fails, the Löwenheim-Skolem fails; I will write a more extensive answer later today, I have to head out in 10 minutes.

Comment: @MihaHabič The argument for $\mathsf{ZF}$ is that if there is a transitive model, then its $L$ is a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ with definable Skolem functions, from which we can build a countable substructure (and apply Mostowski). In this question, we no longer have the ability to carry out that first step of moving to a (self-well-orderable) model of choice.

Comment: Hmmm, a counterexample would be the case where a model of $\sf ZF+\varphi$ cannot be obtained from a model of $\sf ZFC$ in "the usual methods" (forcing/symmetric extensions/etc.), since in such case you can consider $L_\alpha$ for a suitable $\alpha$ and manipulate it into a model of $\sf ZF+\varphi$. But I can't manage to think about any such statement to begin with. @Andres, any ideas?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, so just to clarify what has been said so far; if $\mathrm{DC} \in \Psi$ then Miha's suggestion goes through? I am mainly interested in the case where $\mathrm{AC}$ holds, since I'm trying to get my head around the question: "what formulae in the language of $\{\in\}$ can and cannot be made absolute to transitive models of $\mathrm{ZFC}+\varphi$ for various choices of $\varphi$?" Obviously, the existence of countable transitive models puts fairly strict limits on this kind of things. E.g. We will never be able to make $\aleph_1$ absolute, no matter what $\varphi$ we choose.

Comment: Yes, once you have DC you can deduce the existence of an elementary submodels and collapse them. You might want to clarify your question as it stands.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, thanks; the comments have got me curious, however, to see if this does indeed fail in the absence of $\mathrm{DC}$, so I'm planning to leave the question as-is. Unless you have any specific suggestions for clarification?

Comment: @user18921: In its current form this is a very difficult question, which is very hard to answer, precisely because the counterexample. Since this is just your curiosity being piqued, and not your main objective in this question, I suggest you edit the question to point out that you are interested in the case that $\Psi$ includes the axiom of choice (or sufficient parts of it), but as the discussion in the comment points out, in the complete absence this can yield a different result and you'll be interested in an example for that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, in the case that $\sf DC$ is provable from $\sf ZF+\Psi$. The reason is that $\sf DC$ is equivalent to the following instance of the downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem:

> If $\cal L$ is a countable language in first-order logic, and $M$ is a structure for $\cal L$, then there is a countable $N\subseteq M$ such that $N\prec M$.

In that case, since $\sf ZF+\Psi+\varphi$ prove the existence of a transitive model $(M,\in)$, it proves there is a countable elementary submodel $N$. Since $(N,\in)$ is well-founded we can collapse it to a countable transitive model $N'$, and since $M, N$ and $N'$ have the same theory, $N'$ is a model of $\sf ZF+\varphi$ as well.

On the other hand, if $\Psi$ is not sufficient to prove $\sf DC$, things become immensely more difficult. The reason is that $\sf ZF+\varphi$ is such a theory, that given any model of $\sf ZFC$ we can produce a model of $\sf ZF+\varphi$ in a way that won't violate transitivity (e.g. forcing, inner models, etc.), in which case if $M$ is a transitive model, we can consider $L^M=L_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$, and we can find a countable ordinal $\gamma$ such that $L_\gamma\prec L_\alpha$, and use $L_\gamma$ to produce a countable transitive model for $\sf ZF+\varphi$.

Well, this is of course not sufficient for actually proving that we can dispense with the axiom of choice here. But the trouble is that in order for this to be true, we need $\varphi$ to be a statement that not only doesn't "reflect nicely" (in the sense that we can find a model of $\sf ZFC$ which we can provably make into a countable model) but is not such statement which we can work from any model of an equiconsistent theory.

For example we can always violate $\sf CH$, we can always violate $\sf AC$ in many ways. Any statement which can be forced, or negated using symmetric models or so, and many other statements of this spirit, all will manage to get through, even though we cannot use $\sf DC$ directly.

(If $\varphi$ is such that $\sf ZF+\varphi$ implies there is a canonical inner model of $\sf ZFC+\varphi'$ which satisfies global choice, and $\varphi$ and $\varphi'$ are equiconsistent, then we can repeat the above argument as with $L^M$.)